# What database system to use? (EAV with FK?)

Tags: mysql, database, database-design, nosql, entity-attribute-value

I'm working on an app and I was wondering what sort of database would be best for me.

I'm trying to model listings but attributes/structure vary depending on locale. I'd like to compare, search, etc these listings/attributes across the different locale specific structures. There is always the option of creating a table for each locale but it'd be nice to refer to something like `price = 100` instead of `price_us = 100 OR price_de = 100 OR etc..`

I've read a lot of the questions here regarding EAV in MySQL and it seems that it might not be an ideal solution for me (number of attributes; overly complex).

Is there anything out there that gives me the that flexibility but also something like FK constraints? (limiting to certain attributes or values?)

Comment: What's the problem with EAV? It is always the best approach, especially, when your project gets bigger than expected. It is a logic structure and easy to understand and handle.

Comment: Have you considered separating into price and currency?

Comment: @Andreas that is a gross overgeneralization.  Can you back up or support that claim in any way?

Comment: @Matt, I don't know your background, but I have dealed with complex database structures for couple of years now and had to deal with different sorts of client wishes. Often - of course not always - the changes to a database structure which was not EAV designed caused so much trouble afterwards, to it would have been easier to start directly with a more complex approach. That's why a relational approach makes sense only sense for me for small projects without any/with only small amount of future development.

Comment: Andreas said `What's the problem with EAV? It is always the best approach, especially, when your project gets bigger than expected. It is a logic structure and easy to understand and handle.` do you think the stock market databases are EAV? do banks use EAV? everything has its place, but saying EAV is `always the best approach` is just ridiculous, almost as crazy as saying all columns should just be strings.

Comment: @Andreas: YMMV but for most part EAV schemas are considered time bombs for performance and maintenance for good reasons. Everyone interested should lookup http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/3492/optimizing-query-using-view-on-eav-structure and http://thebuild.com/blog/2011/02/25/10-ways-to-kill-performanc/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well .. i would go with something like :

```
Products           Locales              Prices
----               -----------          -----------
product_id PK      locale_id PK         product_id FK
name               title                locale_id FK
descriptions                            amount
                          if needed >>  currency_id FK
```

Seems like a sensible structure. For the `Prices` table the `PRIMARY KEY` would be composite.

As for selecting product with all the data:

```
SELECT
    Procucts.product_id
    Products.name
    Price.amount
FROM Products
    LFFT JOIN Prices USING(price_id)
    LEFT JOIN Locales USING(locale_id)
WHERE Locale.title = 'uk'
```

Answer (score 0):

EAV modelling is considered an sql anti-pattern and for a host of valid reasons although it is workable and fairly common place in certain sectors ie clinical systems. However it goes against a number of principles that relational databases are based on (hence the term anti-pattern) and adds complexity/overhead to queries whilst making it difficult to maintain the relational context of the data.

Perhaps a few years ago there was little choice but to implement this pattern in MySQL and indeed I have worked on a system that chose this approach. However 12 months ago we switched to a schemaless backend (mongoDB), which is a natural fit for storing records with variable attributes.

IMHO - If you're considering implementing an EAV pattern in MySQL consider a schemaless DB architecture first.